# Using GridView inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an Updatepanel and Gridview inside it.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" OnLoad="uplPanel_Load">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:GridView ID="gvPrList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false"
       AllowSorting="false" CssClass="list-table" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header">
       <Columns>
     <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="button save" OnCommand="onPrItemCmd"
                   CommandName="editRow" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ID") %>' Style="width: 80px" />
               <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="button save" OnCommand="onPrItemCmd"
                   CommandName="deleteRow" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ID") %>' Style="width: 80px" />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

When I click on my buttons inside the Griview, it does not fire the events.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following and it works

I replace asp button with html button and call javascript method to fire Update Panal Load event.

```
<input id="btnDelete1" type="button" onclick="javascript:DeletePrItem('<%# Eval("ID") %>');" value="Delete" class="button save" style="width: 80px" />
```

My Js :

```
    function DeletePrItem(_Id) {
        __doPostBack('<%= uplPanel.ClientID %>', _Id);
    }
```

My Code behind :

```
    protected void uplPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var arg = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

        if (arg != null)
        {
            if (arg != "")
            {
                string recordId = arg.ToString();
                //Do deletetion and rebind data grid

    }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `OnCommand` event of GridView and then handle that inside that event like this:

```
OnRowCommand="gvPrList_OnRowCommand"
```

or alternatively add a click event for the individual button and then handle in the code behind file:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" Text="Edit" CssClass="button save"
                   OnCommand="onPrItemCmd" CommandName="editRow" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("ID") %>' Style="width: 80px" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I already have my code behind handler method for onPrItemCmd event.

Comment: Have you tried adding `onclick` event handler to your button and then checking if that works???

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue where column buttons with a OnClick were causing a postback but the OnClick method was not being hit. When I commented out the update panel and it all worked.

I resolved this issue by adding a postback trigger for the grid within the update panel:

```
</ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
       <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uxWebDataGrid" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Simple and perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would be the Event Handler for your command in the codebehind:

```
protected void onPrItemCmd(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //do whatever you want
        //probably you will need the "ID" or "CommandArgument":
        string myArgumentID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        uplPanel.Update(); //since the UpdatePanel is set *UpdateMode="Conditional"*
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Probably, you might be doing some validation when you click on buttons. If so, you need to add **CausesValidation="false"** in your buttons or links properties

Comment: @Nilaa just wondering why are you using OnLoad="uplPanel_Load"? What are you doing in that procedure? This is a very straightforward task, and it is very weird it is not firing the events. It would be also a good idea to create the page from scratch and see where it breaks...

Comment: I have some another buttons which calls sharepoint model popup. using
__doPostBack('<%= uplPanel.ClientID %>', ''); may be that cause me the issue. any idea?

Comment: I tried using this and get the exception `The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' before Render`.

Comment: @vapcguy try replacing uplPanel with UpdatePanel1, which is your Update Panel's identifier...........

Comment: @aleafonso `UpdatePanel1` *is* my identifier.  `uplPanel` is the OP's identifier.  Wouldn't've matter what I called it was what I was getting at- was just showing it was the same scenario, and you get the error when you call `.Update()` in a place .NET doesn't like (like the button click event).  I managed to solve my issue in a way that has nothing to do with this post, though.  I have a timer as a trigger that updates my panel, and my button click event enables my timer.  I put my `.DataBind()` of a datatable to a gridview in my `Timer1_Tick()` function and it worked fine without `.Update()`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

Depending on your situation, as in mine...All of the clickable controls inside of the update panel I will want to be triggers; So i was simply able to use the UpdatePanel property 'ChildrenAsTriggers="true"' so solve the issue.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPCommunicationlogForm" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
```

This solved my issue, now my edit and delete buttons that are generated from the ItemTemplate inside my gridview call their respective methods on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code into the UpdatePanel.

```
</ContentTemplate> 
 <Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPrList" EventName="Click" />
 </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I get this error : Type 'System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger' does not have a public property named 'EventName'. I am using asp.net 3.5

Comment: protected void Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{                 }  //create this is a dummy event and try

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger' does not have this property

Comment: If it's a `PostBackTrigger`, it doesn't need an event - only `AsyncPostBackTrigger` does.

Answer (score 0):

I added an OnRowCommand Event and add this trigger to the UpdatePanel:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPrList" EventName="RowCommand" />
</Triggers>
```

Note that it's an Async trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. 
In my case I was changing a value in a asp:DropDownList control and then going back to the server to update my asp:GridView which is in a different asp:UpdatePanel. I just forgot to add code to refresh the Update Panel with the list.  Once I did that everything worked fine.

Server side

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = MySQL.DAL.GetRecord(sql);
GV_View.DataSource = ds;
GV_View.DataBind();
UP_MainList.Update(); //refresh the update panel
```

Aspx code

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP_ListChange" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddFilter" DataTextField="Desc" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="Detail" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GV_CodeView_RefreshScreen" ></asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
             </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <div class="medium">Select Filter to view database codes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-row-header" runat="server" id="divList">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UP_MainList" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GV_View" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="id">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Cd" HeaderText="Code" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Short_Desc" HeaderText=" Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="Code_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" onClick="GV_Code_Edit_Click" class="button" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>             
        </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```