# button gridview in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

i use gridview and UpdatePanel in asp.net.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSubject" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div class="c_box" style="height: auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; width:565px; padding-right:140px;">
<asp:GridView ID="gvSubject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    SkinID="gvSubject" ShowHeader="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
    onrowcommand="gvSubject_RowCommand">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="lblCounter" HeaderText="Number" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" ItemStyle-Width="60px"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="lblSubject" HeaderText="Tiltle" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" ItemStyle-Width="300px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="dltSubject" runat="server" CommandName="remove" CommandArgument="lblCounter" ValidationGroup="Subject" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete?')" ImageUrl="~/Style/Pic/pic_delete_small.png" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#000000" />
<EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#00ff00" />
<EmptyDataTemplate>
Not item...
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="gvSubject" eventname="RowCommand" /> 
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

or

```
<asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="dltSubject" eventname="Click" />
```

.

```
protected void gvSubject_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "remove")
        {
            DataTable _dt = (DataTable)Session["Subject"];
            _dt.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Delete();

            gvSubject.DataSource = _dt;
            gvSubject.DataBind();

            Session["Subject"] = _dt;
        }
    }
```

but not work UpdatePanel. please help me for work button gridview in UpdatePanel.

i want work ImageButton in gridview and UpdatePanel.

Comment: you have not set some thing like "EnableViewState=false" in your markup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257581/using-gridview-inside-updatepanel

Comment: Also, TRY REMOVING VALIDATION GROUP. AND REFER ABOVE LINK. IT WOULD SURELY HELP.

Comment: did any of the approaches work?

Comment: i click button but refresh page an page load :-(

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use Triggers for the RowCommand. Also remove rowcommand if you dont want to use besides this button click.

Please specify OnCommand=dtlSubject_Click

I have used here "Number" as commandargument thinking that it is your unique id needed to delete the record.

You need to specify unique column for deletion in commandargument.

```
       <asp:ImageButton ID="dltSubject" runat="server"                                                                  
CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Number")%>'
           ValidationGroup="Subject" OnCommand="dtlSubject_Click"
         OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete?')" ImageUrl="~/Style/Pic/pic_delete_small.png" />
```

And on server side write down following code :

```
 protected void dtlSubject_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
              string uniqueid= e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            //call your procedure here to delete your item.
}
```

Comment: ImageButton in gridview this my code its working but UpdatePanel is not working, i want click to ImageButton and work gridview in UpdatePanel.

Comment: remove triggers and use the commandargument, it would work. It should fire because children controls are triggers by default.

Comment: i use this code, but not working and refresh page and page load