# Update Panel is not partial refresh the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi Have use a GridView inside the Update Panel but it is not partially refresh the GridView i will take CheckBox Inside the ItemTemplate and set their Trigger when i will check the CheckBox whole gridview is refresh but i want to refresh only Respected row when i will check the checkbox here i show the full code.

```
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:GridView ID="gvrank" class="table table-bordered" runat="server" GridLines="None" Width="470px" ForeColor="#333333"
                                                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="gvrank_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="gvrank_RowDataBound">
                                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>

                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxHeader5" onclick="javascript:HeaderClick5(this);" OnCheckedChanged="chkBxHeader5_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                                                            </HeaderTemplate>

                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                                                    <Triggers>
                                                                         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkBxSelect5" EventName="CheckedChanged" />

                                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvrank" EventName="DataBound" />
                                                                    </Triggers>
                                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxSelect5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkBxSelect5_CheckedChanged" />
                                                                    </ContentTemplate>

                                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                            <HeaderStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rank">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="lblrankids" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("rankid") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblranks" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rank") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle Width="90%"></HeaderStyle>
                                                            <ItemStyle Width="90%"></ItemStyle>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No of days">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdays" runat="server" Width="68px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                            <HeaderStyle Width="30%"></HeaderStyle>
                                                            <ItemStyle Width="30%"></ItemStyle>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    </Columns>
                                                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999"></EditRowStyle>
                                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="WhiteSmoke"></HeaderStyle>
                                                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White"></PagerStyle>
                                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>
                                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"></SelectedRowStyle>

                                                </asp:GridView>
                                            </ContentTemplate>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: please help me out sir

Answer (score 0):

What about using `OnRowCommand` on your `DataGridView`.

With `OnCommand`, `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` on your `CheckBox`?

[Here is an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257581/using-gridview-inside-updatepanel)

Comment: <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvrank"EventName="DataBound" />

Comment: please help me out sir

Comment: No you're not using it. EventName is a clear call to classic MVC it looks like it's catch at gridview level when OnCommand / OnRowCommand should be catch at the definition level (Row level or Raisers in your case CheckBox).